# Refreshing with Browser History using React Router returns calls from my API

Tags: node.js, express, react-router, history.js, html5-history

From what I understand, to use the browserHistory object in React Router properly, we need to use a wildcard `*` route so that the user is returned the single page application upon every refresh. Where this becomes a problem is when *my client-side URL is the same as one of my api URLs.*

For example, say I have a website called `example.com` and that one of the pages on this site is `example.com/profile`. If I refresh, the expected behavior is that it will simply reload the website `example.com` and route correctly to `/profile`, since the wildcard route should have returned the client the single page application. Where this doesn't work is if I have an API route `/profile`, i.e. `example.com/profile`.  Now when the user refreshes the page, instead of being returned the the profile page, they are instead returned a JSON response from my API.

Depending on the order in which the wildcard route is declared, I can either have the API response returned on refresh, or the single page app on refresh, but not both when the API url is the same as the client side browser url.

Are there any suggestions around this issue? My current solution is to migrate all of my API routes to have `/api/` prepended to them.

Comment: I'm struggling to add the wildcard route, can you help?
I used: `<Route path='*' component={Homepage} />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure your client routes do not collide with your API routes, and prefixing API routes with `/api` is a pretty standard way to handle this.

There's no real way "around" the issue other than making sure they don't collide – various workarounds might be possible, but it's going to be more clear for everyone involved if routes are unambiguous.